# I need help getting (Main Subfolder) For Each File in selected directory folder using C#

Tags: c#, directory

[image: My Application Image]

i'm trying to get all files inside the folder & Subfolders and get all information for it
but i'm stuk in getting the Main folder Name and path (Grand Father Of Grand Father  Or Grand Father or parent  Depending on how many subfolders ) that contain the subfolders for the file

Ineed to get the Main Contaner Folder for defrent subfolders levels

```
(----------------1--------------)
Main Folder For File            listBox6.Items.Add(?????????);

-Main Folder
-Sub 1
-Sub 1
-Sub 2
-Sub 3
-Sub 4
-Sub 4
-Sub 5
-Sub 5
-Sub 6
-Sub 7

(----------------2--------------)
Path For Main Folder           listBox7.Items.Add(?????????);

-C:\Need Help\Main Folder
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 1
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 1
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 2
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 3
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 4
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 4
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 5
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 5
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 6
-C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 7
```

My Code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Rename_Folders_Files__Subfolders_Subfiles_Move_copy
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Clear();
                listBox2.Items.Clear();
                listBox3.Items.Clear();
                listBox4.Items.Clear();
                listBox5.Items.Clear();
                listBox6.Items.Clear();
                listBox7.Items.Clear();

                textBox1.Text = FBD.SelectedPath;

                String directoryName = FBD.SelectedPath;
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
                if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

                List<String> MyMusicFiles = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.max", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();     // get all files from folders and subfolders

                foreach (string file in MyMusicFiles)
                {
                    FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
                    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(mFile.DirectoryName);
                    int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(mFile.Directory.FullName, "*.max", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length;       /// files count inside each folder

                    if (directoryInfo.Parent != null)
                    {
                        string up2 = directoryInfo.Parent.ToString();
                        listBox4.Items.Add(fCount);
                        // listBox1.Items.Add(mFile.Directory.FullName);
                        listBox2.Items.Add(mFile.Name);
                        listBox3.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(mFile.DirectoryName));
                        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.Combine(mFile.DirectoryName, mFile.Name));
                        listBox5.Items.Add(Directory.GetParent(mFile.FullName).Parent);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string up2 = directoryInfo.Root.ToString().Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)[2];
                        listBox5.Items.Add(up2);
                    }
                }
                label3.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
                label4.Text = listBox2.Items.Count.ToString();
                label8.Text = listBox3.Items.Count.ToString();
                label9.Text = listBox5.Items.Count.ToString();
             }
        }

        public string get_parent_dir_path(string path)
        {
            // notice that i used two separators windows style "\\" and linux "/" (for bad formed paths)
            // We make sure to remove extra unneeded characters.
            int index = path.Trim('/', '\\').LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { '\\', '/' });

            // now if index is >= 0 that means we have at least one parent directory, otherwise the given path is the root most.
            if (index >= 0)
                return path.Remove(index);
            else
                return "";
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string value1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = get_parent_dir_path(value1);
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your construction is quite convoluted. Why not simply display the full path of the directory in the left ListBox with `Path.GetDirectoryName` and the filename in the right ListBox with `Path.GetFileName`? To do what you want, you must start with the parent and walk down the directories, not the other way round.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Olivier 

but my question is 
how can I get the main parent subfolder  for each file in each subfolder whatever how many subfolders levels

for Example 
if the files are in the main Directory folder or the first subfolder just get the path else do loop parent till getting the first subfolder path for each file 
how to code it in c# you are the professional

Comment: How do you know which folder is the main folder? In `"C:\Need Help\Main Folder"` why is `"Main Folder"` the main folder and not `"Need Help"` or even `"C:\"`? You need an exact definition of what the main folder should be. You say *"i'm trying to get all files inside the folder & Subfolders"*. Then, *"the folder"* seems to be what you call "main folder". Therefore, you know it right at the beginning. Why do you need to search for it?

Comment: c:\   Root
\Need Help Parent for the container Folder Main Folder which has files in it 
\Main Folder the container Folder For Files 
i need to get the main subFolder Paht For Each File in this array 
For Example 
File 3.max Full path  C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 1\Sub 8\sub 9\Sub 10\File 3.max
I need This path only  C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 1
and File 11.max Full path C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 7\Sub 18\File 11.max
I need This path only C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 7
and also do the same for each file in Main Folder

With thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Path.GetRelativePath` method to get the path relative to parent of the main container folder.

```cs
static string[] files = {
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\File 1.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 1\File 2.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 1\Sub 8\Sub 9\Sub lO\File 3.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 2\Sub ll\File 4.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 3\Sub 12\File 5.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 4\Sub 13\File 6.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 4\Sub 13\File 7.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 5\Sub 14\File 8.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 5\Sub 14\Sub 15\File 9.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 6\Sub 16\Sub 17\File 10.max",
    @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 7\Sub 18\File 11.max"
};

public static void Test()
{
    string mainFolder = @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder";
    foreach (string file in files) {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
        string mainSubFolder = Path.GetRelativePath(mainFolder, folder);
        if (mainSubFolder == ".") { // We are in the main container folder.
            // Get last part of main container folder.
            mainSubFolder = Path.GetFileName(mainFolder);
        } else {
            // Get first part of the subfolder path.
            int i = mainSubFolder.IndexOf('\\');
            if (i >= 0) {
                mainSubFolder = mainSubFolder.Substring(0, i);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Full path:    {file}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Main folder:  {mainSubFolder, -15} File name:  {fileName}");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\File 1.max
Main folder:  Main Folder     File name:  File 1.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 1\File 2.max
Main folder:  Sub 1           File name:  File 2.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 1\Sub 8\Sub 9\Sub lO\File 3.max
Main folder:  Sub 1           File name:  File 3.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 2\Sub ll\File 4.max
Main folder:  Sub 2           File name:  File 4.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 3\Sub 12\File 5.max
Main folder:  Sub 3           File name:  File 5.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 4\Sub 13\File 6.max
Main folder:  Sub 4           File name:  File 6.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 4\Sub 13\File 7.max
Main folder:  Sub 4           File name:  File 7.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 5\Sub 14\File 8.max
Main folder:  Sub 5           File name:  File 8.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 5\Sub 14\Sub 15\File 9.max
Main folder:  Sub 5           File name:  File 9.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 6\Sub 16\Sub 17\File 10.max
Main folder:  Sub 6           File name:  File 10.max

Full path:    C:\Need Help\Main Folder\Sub 7\Sub 18\File 11.max
Main folder:  Sub 7           File name:  File 11.max
```

---

**UPDATE**

With .NET Framework versions not having the `Path.GetRelativePath` method, you can use this:

```cs
string mainFolder = @"C:\Need Help\Main Folder";
foreach (string file in files) {
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
    string mainSubFolder;
    if (folder == mainFolder) { // We are in the main container folder.
        // Get last part of main container folder.
        mainSubFolder = Path.GetFileName(mainFolder);
    } else {
        mainSubFolder = folder.Substring(mainFolder.Length + 1); // + 1 for the "\".
        // Get first part of the subfolder path.
        int i = mainSubFolder.IndexOf('\\');
        if (i >= 0) {
            mainSubFolder = mainSubFolder.Substring(0, i);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Full path:    {file}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Main folder:  {mainSubFolder,-15} File name:  {fileName}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: That was an amazing answer I mention it as a useful answer but not shown because I'm new here and don't have enough repetition points and for your code, I think this code only works in console applications using .Net Core 2.2   but my application is form windows using .NET Framework 4.8.1 witch Path.GetRelativePath is giving me an error ** CS0117: 'Path' does not contain a definition for 'GetRelativePath' ** I tried several ways to make it work but I can't I know this problem seems easy for you

Comment: You can find a Port of Path.GetRelativePath (.NET Core2) to .NET 4.7.1+ here: https://gist.github.com/antonKrouglov/07ccc117cb8c30ad8994446a86c062e5. Or you could simply cut of the first part of the path by the length of the main container folder: `string mainSubFolder = folder.Substring(mainfolder.Length)` and then not test `if (mainSubFolder == ".")` but `if (mainSubFolder == "")`

Comment: I added a code example working with older .NET Framework versions.

Comment: I really tried to upvote your answer but this message appears Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.